# XMLSimple parse Key Value to Hash

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-simple

i have the following xml:

```
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <string>Some Content</string>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <integer>6</integer>
        <key>Some Text</key>
        <true/>
```

How do i have to configure the Ruby XMLSimple gem to get a Hash with key / value?
Or is XMLSimple the wrong tool?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the key and the value are not grouped inside another XML element, that's rather awful to parse.

Comment: @Michael: Pretty straight forward to parse with Nokogiri, doesn't really look like XMLSimple's style though.

Comment: @mu Agreed, I should phrase my morning answers more carefully. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about XMLSimple but you could use Nokogiri. Something like this should do the trick:

```
def unpack_value(node)
    return node.text      if(node.node_name == 'string')
    return node.text.to_i if(node.node_name == 'integer')
    return true           if(node.node_name == 'true')
    return false          if(node.node_name == 'false')
    # etc.
end

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml>' + your_key_value_xml + '</xml>')
h   = doc.search('key').each_with_object({ }) { |n, h| h[n.text] = unpack_value(n.next_element) }
```

If you're XML already has the `<xml>` wrapper then you don't need to add them.

The [`doc.search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) call will give you an iterator with all the `<key>` elements. Then you iterate with [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) to build the hash. The [`text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text) method gives you the node's content and [`next_element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next_element) gives you the node that immediately follows the `<key>` you have in hand. You might have to tweak `unpack_value` a little to account for all the possible value types but that's pretty straight forward.

This approach will overwrite previous `<key>`s with new ones but it is pretty easy to change it produce an array of little single key hashes if you want to do something with the duplicates.